# Using react-admin's Pagination component in a custom layout

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-admin

React-admin has a `<Pagination />` component [(link)](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Pagination.html).

From my understanding this component needs to be used inside a list component like this: `<List pagination={<Pagination />}>`

I want to use the `<Pagination />` component inside a custom layout, like a `<div>`.

I tried using pagination inside a `<ListBase />` but that still doesn't work.

My question is, how can I add the react-admin pagination to other custom components, for example a grid view, instead of a list view.

What I want to achieve is something like this grid with pagination:
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiV3x.png) or, pagination for a table made out of divs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the source code of `List` to see how it uses that 'pagination' prop?

It is just a rendered component. Nothing more. Just it has to be inside **ListContext**.

You can use it wherever you like.

```
<ListBase>
   <Pagination>
</ListBase>
```

Comment: That code throws this error: `useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component` and I'm not using `<Router>` in my code.

Comment: Did you wrap your app with <Admin>? It has a router inside